# SSHFS - Игнорирование файлов

Tags: linux, sshfs

Есть проекты на различных платформых, фреймворках. При монтировании через sshfs он монтирует всю папку (логично).

Например, мне нужно замонтировать 10 битрикс проектов. В сумме он примонтирует мне около 4.5гб. Если исключить ядро из этого, то получится около 100мб. Есть над чем подумать :)

Может есть связь с .gitignore. В мане и на просторах интернета ничего по этому поводу не нашел.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

монтирование файловой системы (или её части — каталога) — это **не** копирование.

поэтому совершенно не важно (для самой операции монтирования), какой объём дискового пространства занимают файлы в примонтированной ф.с. (каталоге) — единицы байт или миллиарды петабайт.

если вас смущает, что после монтирования вам доступно «слишком много файлов», попробуйте монтировать только те каталоги, с файлами в которых вы работаете.

т.е., если вам надо работать не со всем содержимым каталога, например, `project1`, а только с содержимым каталога `project1/src`, то именно его и указывайте. не:

```
$ sshfs машина:/путь/к/project1 /путь/куда/монтировать
```

а:

```
$ sshfs машина:/путь/к/project1/src /путь/куда/монтировать
```